# Failed to open stream: No such file or directory Error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

First of all I do realize there are already questions like this here, my reason for making a new post about it is I have tried all the solutions I found on stackoverflow and none of them worked for me.

My issues started when I installed [eyewitness](https://github.com/eyewitness/eye) package via composer. I installed it successfully without any errors by running `php artisan eyewitness:install`.

However I have noticed that whenever my queue runs I get this error streamed to my slack channel:

> file_put_contents(/var/app/current/storage/framework/cache/data/0b/fd/0bfda67f938654155945b033c84634aaabaa08f3):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory Level ERROR Exception
>   ```{    "class": "ErrorException",    "message":
>   "file_put_contents(/var/app/current/storage/framework/cache/data/0b/fd/0bfda67f938654155945b033c84634aaabaa08f3):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory",    "code": 0,
>   "file":
>   "/var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:122",
>   "trace": [
>          "{\"function\":\"handleError\",\"class\":\"Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions\",\"type\":\"->\",\"args\":[2,\"file_put_contents(/var/app/current/storage/framework/cache/data/0b/fd/0bfda67f938654155945b033c84634aaabaa08f3):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory\",\"/var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php\",122,{\"path\":\"/var/app/current/storage/framework/cache/data/0b/fd/0bfda67f938654155945b033c84634aaabaa08f3\",\"contents\":\"1546808222i:1;\",\"lock\":true}]}",
>          "/var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:122",
>          "/var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/FileStore.php:65",
>          "/var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/Repository.php:195",
>          "/var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/Repository.php:262",
>          "/var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/CacheManager.php:304",
>          "/var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php:223",
>          "/var/app/current/vendor/eyewitness/eye/app/Notifications/Notifier.php:31",
>          "/var/app/current/vendor/eyewitness/eye/app/Scheduling/BaseEvent.php:236",
>          "/var/app/current/vendor/eyewitness/eye/app/Scheduling/BaseEvent.php:283",
>          "/var/app/current/vendor/eyewitness/eye/app/Scheduling/Event.php:55",
>          "/var/app/current/vendor/eyewitness/e…

Now following various solutions online I did the following:

1. Navigated to my bootstrap/cache folder and deleted all the contents.
2. run `php artisan cache:clear`
3. run `php artisan config:clear`
4. run `php artisan view:clear`
5. run `php artisan config:cache`
6. run `php artisan queue:restart`
7. run `php artisan queue:work &`

After running all the above commands in exactly that order nothing has changed, the error is still being logged every minute and I do not know what to do at this point.

I have the following settings in my .env file:

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
QUEUE_DRIVER=database
```

Comment: Have you checked if the `cache` directory exists at all under `storage/framework`?

Comment: Yes and it exists.

Comment: Then make sure that you have the right permissions on that folder, in order to have access to write to it. 755 are sufficient I believe.

Comment: Would have gotten a "permission denied" if that were the case.

Comment: Have you got with any solution? I'm with the same problem here :'(. Permissions and directories checked.

Comment: I uninstalled it but later I came to realize it had to do with file permissions on my production server.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like permission or folders missing.
Please check if exists the following folders in laravel root project

```
/storage/framework/cache
/storage/framework/views
/storage/framework/sessions
/boostrap/cache
```

And in all there you need write access .